# Saving serbian latin characters in database

Tags: mysql, jsf, jdbc, character-encoding

I have problem with saving serbian latin characters in database, but only when I save it from my jsf application. When I inserting some rows in database directly using SQLyog, everything is fine. When I try insert something from application instead of characters: `č`, `ć` and `đ` in database are inserted question marks.

On the other hand, when I read that row from database everything is shown correctly, without question marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *When I try insert something from application instead of characters: č, ć and đ in database are inserted question marks.*

In other words, the MySQL JDBC driver doesn't support the character encoding in which the characters are originally been submitted with. The MySQL JDBC driver defaults to the platform default encoding when sending character data to the DB, which may be for example ISO 8859-1. You need to tell it not to do that by specifying the `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding` parameters in the JDBC URL.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

When you're using Facelets as view technology, JSF defaults by itself already to UTF-8 when it comes to rendering HTML content and processing submitted parameter values. So the problem is at least not in there.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - [Databases](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#Databases)
- [MySQL Connector/J Manual - 19.3.4.4. Using Character Sets and Unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use JPA also. I tried to add `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` on URL property, but that didn't solve my problem. Is there some property that I can use for this?

Comment: Ah, you're using JPA. Where are you specifying the URL? in `persistence.xml` or in appserver's configuration? If in XML, you should be using `&amp;` instead of `&` because `&` is a special XML entity (the XML error message which you got should also have hinted about it). If in appserver's configuration, then you need to tell more about which one you're using before an answer can be given.

Comment: You're welcome. In the future please don't ignore any new error messages you got. They are not for decoration, they tell something about the cause of the problem. It would be much more informative to share that with us instead of plain saying "that didn't solve my problem", so that we only end up with guessing :)

Comment: @BalusC I have been using JSF for about two years. I faced many difficulties, searched Google and most of them are solved by your posts. Thank you so much! :-)