# Display all special characters html/php

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have a database which contains a lot of names including foreign names which have special characters e.g.  Žigić

When echoing these names some of the characters show as question marks, where as some show because I am using charset ISO-8859-1

For example when I echo the name Žigić from the database, it appears like this:

> Žigi?

I am currently using this code to try and enable all special characters

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

I have tried UTF-8 but this just prints the name like this:

```
�igi?
```

This is the full code which I am trying to use:

```
$getPlayerStats = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `playerstats` WHERE `playerid` = '".$_GET['id']."'");

echo '<meta charset="iso-8859-1"><table border="1">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Second Name</td>

</tr>';

while ($playerStats = mysqli_fetch_array($getPlayerStats))//Loop it.
{




    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$playerStats['firstname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$playerStats['lastname'].'</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Note this problem is not just for 1 character or one name, the names database contains hundreds of names.

Can anyone help me out, thanks.

Comment: this might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311462/saving-serbian-latin-characters-in-database

Comment: have you tried utf8_encode($string) ?

Comment: When I try this it prints the name Žigić out as ÂŽigi?

Comment: not an answer but maybe the html/unicode stuff would help. Like  `&#163;` rather than £.

Comment: I would use that but it is not just one character that displays as a question mark, and finding each one would take forever as there are more than 1000 names in the database.

Comment: which encoding are you using in your database?

Comment: I am using this collation in the db: utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 2):

In order to maintain uniform UTF-8 encoding throughout your project,
try

```
$pdo->exec('set names utf8');
```

before your query, or ideally append the charset to your connection string like so:

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"
```

and remove this part:

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

Make sure the encoding for your page is UTF-8, you could add the following to the head tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**Edit:** Seeing your use of `$db` had me make the false assumption that you are using PDO. As specified in another answer to your question, you should use [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset) in order to set the charset for your connection with MySQL. The collation for your database should not matter for the encoding you receive your data as, as long as it has the characters you require.

All in all, just ensure consistency of the charset you use for the connection to the database and for your HTML output and you should be fine as long as the charset you picked  has the characters you require.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the database<->php transport encoding:

```
mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
```

before making any queries. Keep the page encoding declaration as UTF-8, since your data is going to be UTF-8 now.

Answer (score 0):

i may be wrong but i had this problem last year with � open it up in regular text pad or word pad and see if there's a space next to where you output the query i did that and it got rid of them

or maybe download your db and open the sql file with those programs and do the same process maybe it will show the � symbols.