# Trying to query to Excel using JDBC Driver

Tags: java, excel, odbc

I´m using ODBC driver to query data to an Excel Spreadsheet data source. However i get an error when i try to select a UNICODE field in the file (e.j Compañia ) :

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Excel] Pocos par?metros. Se esperaba 2.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:252)
```

My query is something like this "SELECT COMPAÑIA,AGENCIA,PAIS,AÑO,MES FROM SHEET", and only fails when i have characters like "Ñ" in the query.

Comment: try this thread, User seems to facing similar problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311462/saving-serbian-latin-characters-in-database

Comment: It looks looks you are running this on a PC, and you say the data you are trying to read is coming from an Excel file.  So why are you using a JDBC driver designed specifically for a DB2 server on an IBM iSeries (or related) machine?

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I was confused about the driver.